# Stack pointer register for AArch64

Tags: assembly, arm, heap-memory, arm64, stack-memory

I want to initialize the stack and heap in my assembly start-up file for armv8 bare metal application.
I am using AArch64 Fast Modal simulator for testing.
Simulator is always stuck on execute "stp" assembly instruction.
Here is my code.

```
.section .text, "ax"
.global _start
_start:
ldr   x1, _heap_start_ptr
movz w0, #0x16 /* SWI: Heapinfo */
hlt #0xf000

/* Pointer to heap start  */
ldr     x2, _heap_start_ptr
/* Pointer to stack base  */
ldr     x1, _stack_ptr

mov     sp, x1
ldr     x0,[x2,#16]   /* Stack base */
and     sp, x0, #~15

/* Pointer to heap start  */
ldr     x1, _heap_limit
ldr     x0, [x2, #8]  /* heap limit */
and     x1,x0, #~15

/* Now this code stuck the simulator  */
/* Setup an initial dummy frame with saved fp=0 and saved lr=0 */
mov     x29, #0
stp     x29, x29, [sp, #-16]!
mov     x29, sp


ldr w1, =hello
movz w0, #0x04 /* SWI: write0 */
hlt #0xf000

b _start_c_code   /* This code initialize some newlib routine and jump to c/c++ code  */
hello:
.ascii "Hello, world!\n"

.align 3
_heap_start_ptr:
         .dword _heap_start
_heap_limit_ptr:
         .dword _heap_limit
_stack_ptr:
         .dword _stack
```

I am initializing the stack and heap for running c/c++ bare metal application.

comment out the "stp" instruction line

```
//stp     x29, x29, [sp, #-16]!
```

simulator show print "Hello World!" on hosted mode.
but with "stp" instruction, fast modal always goes on stuck state.
Please note "stp" is equal "push" instruction in armv8 and without "stp" we cannot even push anything on stack.

Now Question:
* Why "sp" does not give privilege to push on stack?
* Am I actually initializing correct heap and stack?
* Is there require any other low level initialization to use the stack?

Comment: Disregarding the confusing "set up the stack twice, two different ways" logic, what's the value of `_stack` that you're loading? You're most likely taking a fault due to nonsense in the SP - plugging a debugger into the model to look would be a good idea.

Comment: A poke around the [Fast Models documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0837b/Chunk121415449.html#rob1396282425176) suggests the semihosting stuff deals in _virtual_ addresses. which are nowhere near where the RAM is if you haven't turned the MMU on.

Comment: 1) make sure _heap_start_ptr isn't zero. 2) make sure you are initializing the correct stack pointer. If the system is configured to use a different stack pointer for each exception level you may encounter an issue. The first time you enter el_n you need to set sp_eln before you use the sp register. I didn't read all your code so  I'm not sure if this is the issue, but I see you using sp without independent el configuration.